# ActiveRecord doesnt fetch certain fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

i'm using a devise model for registration on which i included additional fields.

this is my users table schema

```
 create_table "users", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "provider",                             default: "email", null: false
    t.string   "uid",                                  default: "",      null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",                   default: "",      null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                        default: 0,       null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.string   "username",                                               null: false
    t.string   "email",                                                  null: false
    t.integer  "role",                                 default: 0,       null: false
    t.datetime "premium_expires_at"
    t.string   "token",                                default: "",      null: false
    t.text     "tokens",                 limit: 65535
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["uid", "provider"], name: "index_users_on_uid_and_provider", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true, using: :btree
  end
```

However, when querying the table through activeRecord (User model) , i'm not able to fetch certain columns which belong to devise.

example

```
userList = User.select("id, confirmation_token, confirmed_at, username, uid, role")
```

logging userList gives me

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, uid: "foo@foo.com", username: "bowie", role: "admin", avatar: nil>, #<User id: 2, uid: "bar@bar.com", username: "wilson", role: "user", avatar: nil>, #<User id: 3, uid: "sp@sp.com", username: "Cartman", role: "user", avatar: nil>]>
```

the confirmation_token field and confirmed_at token field isnt being retrieved. Is there something else i should be doing?

Comment: What does it print when you `puts userList.confirmation_token` or `puts userList.confirmed_at`?

Comment: hmm .. i'm actually able to retrieve the values when i loop through the array as user.confirmation_token .. but it still doesnt seem to be part of the array. more like a method which retrieves the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at the [Authenticatable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb) module from devise. They specially blacklist (see `BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION` constant) these attributes for serialization. So, I think that's why you aren't able to see them in the console.